Identification of bone?tooth? found on beach
Need help identifying what I think is a tooth. We found it on the beach near Galveston, Tx. I took it to a natural science museum for help with ID and they agreed it appeared to be a tooth but not sure what from. They thought possibly marine mammal? Anyways I'm posting here with pictures in hopes someone can identify it's origins. Thank you




Yep, I found it myself. Boliver peninsula

that doesn't look like a tooth, teeth have roots and are no hollow. more likely a fish bone, and there are a lot of weird fish bones. you may want to change the title so you get people who are more familiar with fish.

I don't believe it is hollow except for that small area at the top. It seemed like maybe that's where the roots were. But that is interesting. Thanks for the insight

Its very likely a hyperostotic fish bone - or swollen bones which occurs in around 80 species.

Here's the location against the vertebrae

Here's its location against the silver bream skeleton

Here's a brief description of the skeletal phenomena

Oh wow interesting! So it's actually an abnormality. That makes since as it's so strange lol. Thank you for solving this mystery for us!!

Please cut the sources of your images (ideally beneath each image.  caption  works well
